# question marks (???) when connect to excel file with ODBC driver , FDConnection component

Tags: excel, delphi, firedac

With FDConnection component I read Excel files(xls or xlsx), using ODBC driver, but non-English symbols (for example, Russians, Georgians) are replaced with "???" marks.
In FDComponent I choose only Driver_id "odbc". In Driver combobox I select or not "Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xls)" nothing changed. FDConnection component hasn't parameter like 'character set' to set it to Unicode or utf-8 or utf-16 value.
How and which properties of FDConnection I have to set to read non-English symbols?

Delphi 10.4.2, Office Professional Plus 2021.

in OnCreate procedure I write this code but nothing has been changed:

```
FDConnection1.Connected          := false;
FDConnection1.Params.Values['Database']:= .... 
FDConnection1.Params.Values['OpenMode']     := 'CreateUTF16';
FDConnection1.Params.Values['StringFormat'] := 'Unicode';
FDConnection1.Connected:=true;
fdQuery1.open;
```

Connection Info of FDConnection component:

```
Connection definition parameters
    ================================
    Database=D:\Delphi Projects\Excel\DB\myData.xls
    DriverID=ODBC
    ================================
    FireDAC info
    ================================
    Tool = RAD Studio 10.4
    FireDAC = 27.0.0 (Build 99682)
    Platform = Windows 32 bit
    Defines = FireDAC_NOLOCALE_META;FireDAC_MONITOR
    ================================
    Client info
    ================================
    Loading driver ODBC ...
      Loading odbc32.dll driver manager
      Creating ODBC environment handle
      Variable [ODBCDriver]: [Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)]
    Driver Manager version = 03.81.19041.0000
    ================================
    Session info
    ================================
    Current catalog = 
    Current schema = 
    Driver name = odbcjt32.dll
    Driver version = 10.00.19041
    Driver conformance = 3
    DBMS name = EXCEL
    DBMS version = 08.00.0000
```

Comment: But your [`ConnectionString` does nowhere define `'CharacterSet=utf8'`](http://forums.unigui.com/index.php?/topic/8204-characterset-mess-solved/#comment-41937). Also have a read on [Unicode support](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Unicode_Support_(FireDAC)).

Comment: @AmigoJack , Wow! It works. I change language for non-unicode languages from English to Georgian and it works fine for Georgian and Russian symbols. However, it doesn't matter if I choose excel driver or not in FDConnection parameters.  It works in both cases.

Comment: @AmigoJack , but If I want get data from xlsx file it's not possible, there is not odbc driver for xlsx files in combobox list.. I get error: "[ODBC Excel driver] external table is not in the expected format.".  Is there a way arond this problem?

Comment: That contradicts to your description "_I read excel files(xls or xlsx), using odbc driver_" and also is not your question's issue. Different problem = different question - by now you should know how this website works.